# Rename multiple files in sub directories to their directory names

Tags: linux, shell-script, files

I have a folder on my desktop named Models. In the folder, there are named folders with jpeg files without the .jpg extensions. The jpeg file names are random hashes. I would like to use a bash script to batch rename these jpeg files to their directory names with increments and append the .jpg extension on each file.

It's basically something like

Models/

```
 Alice/
      a5ccB2ff3e
      ee420bc4a
      2acee54dc
      ...
 Alex/
      de33fa24c0
      d1eaa48e0a
      ...
```

And I want to to be like

Models/

```
 Alice/
      Alice001.jpg
      Alice002.jpg
      Alice003.jpg
      ...

 Alex/
      Alex001.jpg
      Alex002.jpg
      ...
```

Comment: Please show us, what have you tried so far

Comment: I don't even know how to do a sub directory search. Trying to show what I tried would just be toying. I would try in php but bash is a different language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description of your question I am assuming that ***total no. of files in a folder does not exceed 999.***

This is a simple bash script run it in your top directory i.e Models:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ./*
do
if [ -d "$i" ]
then
j=001
for k in "$i"/*
do
mv "$k" "$i"/"$i""$j".jpg
j=${j#0}
if [ ${j:0:1} -eq 0 ]
then 
j=${j#0}
fi
(( j++ ))
j=`printf '%03i' $j`
done
fi
done
```

It will first check every file in Models, whether it is a directory or not by `if [ -d "$i" ]` . Then for each file in this directory it will change their names by `mv "$k" "$i"/"$i""$j".jpg`. And

```
j=${j#0}
if [ ${j:0:1} -eq 0 ]
then 
j=${j#0}
fi
```

Above code will remove all the zeroes from beginning so that you will not get the error like:

```
 ((: 008: value too great for base (error token is "008")
 printf: 008: invalid octal number
```

And

```
j=`printf '%03i' $j`
```

will make value of `j` 3 digits long.

Comment: It worked partially but threw an error. It only renamed 8 pictures in each folder and deleted the rest (I have backup, don't worry).


Then it printed this in the console:


/home/myName/Desktop/for.sh: line 13: ((: 008: value too great for base (error token is "008")

Comment: @Boygee updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try also this simplified version of Debian_yadav's proposal:

```
for i in *
  do    if [ -d "$i" ] && cd "$i"
          then  j=0
                for k in *
                  do    ((j++))
                        echo mv "$k" $(printf "%s%03d.jpg" $i $j )
                  done
                cd ..
          fi
  done
```

The `echo` is for debugging only; remove if happy with what you see.

It `cd`s into each directory available, resets the counter, loops across all target files, increments the counter for each, and the does the rename.